# Access translation file (i18n) from inside rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, translation, rails-i18n

What I have in my model is:

```
def body_color_enum
  [
    ['Aqua', '#009c9c'],
    ['Grey', '#6d6e71'],
    ['Yellow', '#ffe600'],
    ['White', 'white']
  ]
end
```

I want these values to come from the translation file 'en.yml'

```
en:
  group:
    hero:
      hex1: '#6d6e71'
      name1: 'Dark grey'
      hex2: '#ccc'
      name2: 'Light grey'
      hex3: '#0099ce'
      name3: 'Blue'
      hex4: '#ffffff'
      name4: 'White'
```

I have tried this:

```
def body_color_enum
  [
    [t('group.hero.name1'), '#009c9c'],
    ['Grey', '#6d6e71'],
    ['Yellow', '#ffe600'],
    ['White', 'white']
  ]
end
```

But i get this error:

```
undefined method `t' for #<Group:0x007fabad847ac8>
```

So what I'm asking is how can I access my local file from the model so I can set my values in the body_color_enum method.

Comment: `I18n.t('group.hero.name1')`

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Call:

```
I18n.t
```

instead of simple `t`. `t` is a helper method only available in the views, delegating the whole logic to `I18n` module.

UPDATE:

As mentioned in the comments, view helper is not only delegating to the `I18n` module, it makes sure that you can use a default scopes as well.

Comment: To explain why: this happens because `t` is a view helper. View helpers are not available in models (among other places), so the full call to `I18n.t` is needed.

Comment: Lovely stuff. I needed this to access i18n within a "cell" - worked like a charm.

Comment: it's worth mentioning, that `I18n.t` is not the same as calling `translate` in view https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.1.1/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/translation_helper.rb#L18

Comment: Any way to make I18n helper available in model, so we can just call `t()` instead of `I18n.t`?  Many valid use cases for calling translations from within the model, including customizing error messages on validations, etc. ..

Comment: You would have to add `include ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper` to the model. From the api: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper.html  but this breaks the convention. Better off sticking to `I18n.t` like the answer states.

Answer (score 2):

```
# constants
def self.option_enum
    [ 
      [ I18n.t('enum.amount'), 'A' ], 
      [ I18n.t('enum.percentage'), 'P' ] 
    ]
end
```

Comment: This simply won't work with languages like German where every noun start with a capital letter. Capitalization is a matter of the language itself and should not be "fixed" inside the code